# JBOSS AS 7.1.1 RestEasy HTTP Status 500 - Bad arguments passed

Tags: jboss, resteasy

I am having a Session Bean exposed via RESTful interface in JBoss AS7.1.1; That is having both a EJB module and a WAR module, the WAR module having a (maven) dependency on the EJB module; The WAR is just web.xml with RestEasy directives.
(modelled along https://github.com/alexcpn/rest_in_sessionbean )

```
Stateless
@Path("sessionbean")
public class ControllerRest  {
@EJB
Controller mroController;

    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public ControllerRest() {

    }


    @GET
    @Path("/test")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String test( ){

        return "Hello from Mro SessionBean Jar ";
    }
```

I am intermittently getting  'HTTP Status 500 - Bad arguments passed' error while invoking the REST interface; ( plain REST calls and ones with Query interface). It seems some problem with  class loading
as described in -https://community.jboss.org/thread/175629. Looks like a bug in RESTEasy integration to JBOSS.

```
17:31:28,142 SEVERE [org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-4) Failed executing GET /sessionbean/test: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.InternalServerErrorException: Bad arguments passed to public java.lang.String com.nokia.oss.MroControllerRest.test()  ( )
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:196) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:257) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:222) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:211) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:525) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:502) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:119) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
```

Comment: Could you describe how you call your RESTful Service?

Comment: Via browser http://localhost:8080/Mroservlet/rest/sessionbean/startmro?scopename=werwerwe

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. So, i suppose the problem is in old version of library resteasy-jaxrs from JBoss.
All i did is moved to wildfly, but i think it could be fixed with new version of a library.